DIgital QPSK demodulation of I/Q Data (Costas Loop, Symbol Sync, etc.)
I am trying to implement in hardware demodulation of QPSK-modulated I/Q samples from an SDR. The data would come from the reception of satellite transmissions. My approach is based on mapping onto hardware the architecture provided in GNURadio's wiki page 
However I am confused by the usage of the Symbol Sync block. From what I understand, the Costas loop already provides carrier recovery as well as phase/frequency alignment. Concretely, what function does it provide that the Costas loop cannot accomplish?
I am studying EE but have little formation in these topics, pointers to books/articles/other study material about these topics would be much appreciated :)
Thank you
Extra questions:
Considering the noticeable Doppler shift of received satellite data, is a Costas Loop still advised?
Would there be a way to combine both the Symbol Sync Loop and the Costas Loop if they are both necessary?
Does it even make sense to this in hardware (FPGA)?

The Symbol Sync block estimates and tracks what it thinks is the center of your symbol pulses and then resamples and decimates the input to provide output samples at the center of the symbols.  That's it.

https://www.gnuradio.org/grcon/grcon17/presentations/symbol_clock_recovery_and_improved_symbol_synchronization_blocks/Andy-Walls-Samples-to-Digital-Symbols.pdf
